# Deploy same code to two environments in AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two environments in the same elastic beanstalk application, one is web environment and the other is worker environment, they share the same code.

Now I have to run `eb deploy web && eb deployer worker` to make it work, it takes a few minutes for each deployment, is it possible to deploy code to these two environments in one command?

Comment: You can fire the commands off and put them in background: `eb deploy web & eb deployer worker &`

Comment: @Raf I'm running the deploy cmd inside a docker container, run in background is not what I want

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to deploy to two environments at once using `eb deploy`. However, you might want to investigate the `--version` flag - by doing `eb deploy web && eb deployer worker` you're actually doing the packaging step twice (and creating two separate zip files) rather than deploying the exact same artifact to both environments.

Comment: @Brian I have checked the output of the deployment, the most part of time it takes is deploying rather than packing/uploading, so it doesn't make sense to using `--version` flag